# HTML input with numbers only and suffix

Tags: javascript, numbers, suffix

Im using [inputAffix.js](https://github.com/jcoc611/InputAffix) lib for showing suffix in html input. I want that field can be filled only with numbers, but also to contain text suffix.

```js
 $(function(){
  $("#amount").suffix(" EUR");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://zdravem.com/js/InputAffix.js"></script>

<input id="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="30 EUR"></input>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can try below code

```js
$(function(){
   $("#amount").suffix(" EUR");
});
  
function isNumberKey(evt) {
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
   if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://zdravem.com/js/InputAffix.js"></script>

<input id="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="30 EUR" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></input>
```

Hope it will help you